# "Easy your uncle Fred"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

What does it mean when someone says "take it easy" and another one replies "easy your uncle Fred's ass"? Does it mean " F*ck you"?

Comment: In general, appending "my ass", "your ass", "my eye", and other variants are a sarcastic, and mostly rude, way of suggesting that whatever came before is false or impossible or similar.

Comment: It sounds like a variation of ["My arse!"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/my-arse) [BrE] ("My ass!" [AmE]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As those in the comments have mentioned, it means the same as "my ass", which is another way of sarcastically saying "Yeah right." or "I don't agree with what you've just told me." They're sardonically saying, "There is no way I will be able to take it easy."

In this case, the person just chose to reference Uncle Fred's ass instead of their own.